# Dynamically add a Property to a System.object?

Tags: c#, object, properties

I got a list of different objects that I defined in different classes and I'd like to add a string property "Name" to all these objects. Is that possible ?

I don't have that much code to provide as my classes are very simple/classic ones.

Thanks in advance for any help !

(edit : I don't want to inherit from an abstract class that adds this property ! In fact, I don't want to modify at all my class that define my object. That's what i call "Dynamically" in the title.

What I want is something like :

```
myObject.AddProperty(string, "Name");
```

or

```
myObject.AddAttribute(string, "Name");
```

(I don't know how it is exactly called)

and then I can do :

```
myObject.Name = "blaaa";
```

Comment: Can you define a wrapper class that will contain your original type in addition to the new properties you want?

Comment: ExpoandoObject in .NET Framework 4.0 : Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an abstract class that all of your other classes could inherit:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyCommonString { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyBaseClass() { }
}

//Create instance of foo
Foo myFoo = new Foo();

//MyCommonString is accessible since you inherited from base
string commonString = myFoo.MyCommonString;
```

**EDIT (per new requirement)**

Since you don't want to touch the original classes in the DLL, I'd take this [similar] approach:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyCommonString { get; set; }
}

//This class definition lives in the DLL and remains untouched
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }
}

//This partial class definition lives in [insert new project name here]
public partial class Foo : MyBaseClass
{
    public Foo () { }
}
```

Notice that `Foo` is now a partial class. You're not touching the existing class definition in the DLL, you're extending it.

**EDIT (per newer new requirement)**

Given your requirements (no editing of original class), what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: my classes are defined in DLL so I'd REALLY like to avoid this solution.
I thought about it but let's consider that I can't do it

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne, that information should have been in your original post. Edit incoming, but you'll probably not like it either :)

Comment: yep, don't like it cause the problem is quite the same, I have to edit my class so that it inherits from the abstract one and it really doesn't fit with my project :(

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne, you don't have to edit your original class using the solution I posted under the "Edit" section. You're simply adding a partial class definition of `Foo`. Any way you slice it, your requirement states that you want to edit the base class.

Comment: humm, le'ts say that my class is :

    public class Foo
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    }

Without editing this code, I really don't understand how to apply your solution :o

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne, I'm not sure what you're asking from your last comment. I've edited and commented my solution in an attempt to make it more clear.

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne, You would apply it by creating a new class in your current solution called `Foo.cs`. By using the `partial` keyword, you can extend the original `Foo` class that is defined in the DLL. Have a look at my examples :)

Comment: Ok get it but you suppose that you know your class name ! i'd like to add this property to (let's say) hundreds of different classes. That's why I'd want a sort of "myObject.AddProperty(---)"

Comment: I would like 3 million dollars =). Given your requirements (no editing of original class), what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: give you the acceptance for your effort, I'll have to find another way without this property :(

Comment: Why do you say that a partial class can be defined this way? The solution proposed here will not compile for two reasons: both parts of the partial class definition need to be in the same assembly, and both parts need to be marked partial. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to hard code a Hashtable named CustomProperties
Now you can fill this Hashtable with custom properties

Something like that:

```
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.SetProperty("abc", 123);
        myClass.SetProperty("bcd", "bla");
        myClass.SetProperty("cde", DateTime.Now);

        MessageBox.Show(myClass.GetProperty("abc").ToString());

class MyClass
{
    private Hashtable MyProperties { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyProperties = new Hashtable();
    }

    public object GetProperty(string name)
    {
        return MyProperties.Contains(name) ? MyProperties[name] : null;
    }

    public void SetProperty(string name, object value)
    {
        if (MyProperties.Contains(name))
            MyProperties[name] = value;
        else
            MyProperties.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt really understand what you mean, you got a short sample code that I can understand ?

Comment: Edited my question but your solution modify the Class so it doesnt fit with what I want :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the new C# 4.0 `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
obj.Value = 10;
var action = new Action<string>((l) => Console.WriteLine(l));
obj.WriteNow = action;
obj.WriteNow(obj.Value.ToString());
```

You can not do this with `object`, but the `ExpandoObject` will do just fine.

But... overuse dynamic typing and you'll find yourself in a maintenance nightmare in the near future.